# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar las etiquetas de Git que solo tengo en local?

Tags: git, git-tag

En mi repositorio trabajo con etiquetas para marcar las versiones que voy sacando. Cuando está todo bien hago push con `git push --follow-tags`.

Sin embargo, haz veces en que las etiquetas que he creado no funcionan bien y quiero eliminarlas. `git tag -d "nombre"` suele funcionar, pero a veces me da error.

¿Hay alguna manera de actualizar el listado de etiquetas para que las que no existen en remote sean eliminadas?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1841341/1983854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde la versión 2.17 de Git tienes la opción de hacer:

```
git fetch --prune --prune-tags
```

De este modo, git hará "prune", es decir, *podará* las etiquetas que ya no están en remoto.

Es posible configurar Git para que haga esto cada vez que actualice el repositorio siempre que hagas `git fetch`:

```
git config fetch.pruneTags true
```

Respuesta original y más detalles en [esta respuesta de Nicholas Carey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297675/1983854) a [Remove local git tags that are no longer on the remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1841341/1983854).