# ¿Cómo eliminar todas las etiquetas de repositorio local?

Tags: git

¿se pueden eliminar todas las etiquetas del repositorio local?

Parece que tengo la opción de eliminar una por una, por ejemplo:

```
git tag tag_name --delete
```

o [eliminar las que no están en el remoto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/286681/20709):

```
git fetch --prune --prune-tags
```

Pero, ¿con independencia de las etiquetas del remoto? Es decir si por ejemplo no tuvieramos acceso a este

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Eliminar todas las etiquetas locales. (Opcional recomendado)**

```
git tag -d $(git tag -l)
```

**2. Obtenga todas las etiquetas del control remoto. (Opcional recomendado)**

`git fetch`

**3. Eliminar todas las etiquetas remotas.**

`git push origin --delete $(git tag -l) # Pushing once should be faster than multiple times`

---

Puede obtener una lista de etiquetas remotas a través de `git ls-remote`. Para enumerar las etiquetas en el repositorio al que hace referencia `origin`, debe ejecutar:

`git ls-remote --tags origin`

Eso devuelve una lista de hashes y nombres de etiquetas amigables, como:

```
94bf6de8315d9a7b22385e86e1f5add9183bcb3c        refs/tags/v0.1.3
cc047da6604bdd9a0e5ecbba3375ba6f09eed09d        refs/tags/v0.1.4
...
2f2e45bedf67dedb8d1dc0d02612345ee5c893f2        refs/tags/v0.5.4
```

Ciertamente, podría armar un script bash para comparar las etiquetas generadas por esta lista con las etiquetas que tiene localmente. Eche un vistazo a `git show-ref --tags`, que genera los nombres de las etiquetas en la misma forma que `git ls-remote`).

Como un aparte, `git show-ref` una opción que hace lo contrario de lo que le gustaría. El siguiente comando enumeraría todas las etiquetas en la rama remota que no tiene localmente:

`git ls-remote --tags origin | git show-ref --tags --exclude-existing`

Fuente:

> [How to remove all git origin and local tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44702758/8933039)
>
> [Remove local git tags that are no longer on the remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1847797/8933039)
>
> Adicional, revise [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373319/8933039) también es interesante.

Comment: El primero comando es el que estaba buscando, borra todas las etiquetas locales sin ninguna otra consideración `git tag -d $(git tag -l)` Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido, esta es una buena opción también: `$ git tag -d $(git tag)`

Comment: Sí, lo he pensado. Suelo usar `git tag` para listar, aunque `git tag -l` o `git tag --list` son más descriptivos, como ejemplo, ya que se combinan dos comandos.